# How to specify DateTime() for a MySQL table in Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I try and create a table containing a DATETIME() field, I am required to enter a number between the parenthesis.

I selected 20 and it gave an error stating that 6 is the maximum.  I changed it to 6 and it worked. e.g. DATETIME(6).

However, I do not know what 6 represents.  Does anyone know the composition of the DATETIME argument?

Comment: The `DATETIME` type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays `DATETIME` values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the "()" it's a default effect when you choice a type.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`date_stat` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```